# How to get project IDs for all repositories in a GitLab group (python-gitlab)?

Tags: python, gitlab

I'd like to automate a number of processes across all repositories in my collaboration's GitLab Group, which (at least as of GitLab API v4) requires project IDs rather than names.

Does the `python-gitlab` library have a method for grabbing all project IDs for a given group?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there is exactly such a method!

I've written a [script](https://gitlab.com/glass-docs/git-tips/-/blob/main/gitlab/get_project_ids.py) which will fetch a list of all projects and extract their IDs:

```py
#### get_project_ids.py ####
# gets all project ids for a gitlab group
# assumes GitLab 'private_token' is set to env. variable called $GITLAB_TOKEN

import gitlab, os

# authenticate
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', private_token=os.environ['GITLAB_TOKEN'])

# set gitlab group id
group_id = 55555
group = gl.groups.get(group_id, lazy=True)

#get all projects
projects = group.projects.list(include_subgroups=True, all=True)

#get all project ids
project_ids = []
for project in projects:
    project_ids.append((project.path_with_namespace, project.id))
    
print(project_ids)
```

If you then need to operate on these repositories, you can use the `requests` library to make http calls via python, for example:

```py
import requests

# unprotect master branch for all projects
for pid in project_ids:
    r = requests.request('DELETE', 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{}/protected_branches/master'.format(pid[1]), headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN' : token})
```